Integrating Opensearch with Ruby on Rails
Currently, my Rails application utilizes Elasticsearch with the elasticsearch-model and elasticsearch-rails gems for integration:
require 'elasticsearch/model'
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Elasticsearch::Model
  include Elasticsearch::Model::Callbacks

  settings :index => {
    :number_of_shards => 1,
    :max_result_window => MAX_RESULT_WINDOW
  },
  :analysis => {
    :filter => {
      :email => {
        :type => 'pattern_capture',
        :preserve_original => 1,
        :patterns => [
          '([^@]+)',
          '(\\p{L}+)',
          '(\\d+)',
          '@(.+)',
          '([^-@]+)'
        ]
      }
    },
    :analyzer => {
      :email => {
        :tokenizer => 'uax_url_email',
        :filter => [
          'email',
          'lowercase',
          'unique'
        ]
      }
    }
  } do
    mappings do
      indexes :sent_at, type: 'date', fields: { raw: { type: 'date', index: 'not_analyzed' } }
    end
  end

  def as_indexed_json(options={})
    self.as_json(
      only: [:id, :send_at],
      methods: [:student_email, :subject, :deleted_at]
    )
  end
end

Article.__elasticsearch__.create_index!
Article.import

Now, I intend to transition to OpenSearch, but I haven't found any gem that provides similar functionality, such as
Opensearch.client.import

Does anyone have suggestions on how to achieve this migration? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Searchkick supports both Elasticsearch and Opensearch:
https://github.com/ankane/searchkick

Yes, can use Searchkick for my case, thanks!
